# Football Manager 2013 Internet Requirement

Tags: football-manager-2013

I want to know that how much of mb i have to browse or download for football manager 2013 pc game. How much of mb is required to install football manager 2013 or how much time it will take.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are going to download the game from Steam, it will show you something like this:

[image]

Which gives you the information you seek. Obviously, the time is dependent on the bandwidth of your connection.

When running, the game doesn't have much need for an online connection outside of the DRM of Steam.